# Google Chrome Frame and corporate policies

Tags: google-chrome-frame

My question is,since Google Chrome Frame launches and installs itself in a browser ,can it go through the strict Corporate policies some company have which prohibits them install and download any software?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. But you'd better stop thinking about loopholes in corporate security.

If you need something for private use - bring personal laptop to work (surely without connecting it to corporate network).

Comment: No Sir I'm talking about those companies that have handcuff-type corporate policy where users are bound to just using IE. because Im thinking of having our website support google chrome frame.